# How to regenerate a CSR from a first CSR

Tags: openssl, csr, crt

Context:

1. we use RSA to sign some documents
2. we have a private key
3. we sent to "The Other party" a certificate corresponding to that key a long time ago
4. the "Other party" also use the certificate to check other fields against the signed document (for example the document author in the document metadata should match email contained in the certificate)
5. I need to regenerate a certificate as the old one is going to expire

The certificate has a LOT of field, so I would rather reuse it to regenerate the CSR. In that case I know the `openssl` command to get back a CSR from a `.crt`

The problem is I only have the original CSR, but not the certificate.

Is there a command to regenerate a CSR from an original one ?

Comment: You can use the same CSR as last time as long as the keys haven’t changed, or the other data.

Comment: @user207421 , thanks , if you can backup that with some data/source, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Why? Just try it. I've been doing it for years.

Comment: I tried it and indeed it worked, my point was more so that to have an authoritative answer, so that the next guy seeing this question can see "ok I see, that's because in RFC 42, no date-related field are present in a CSR" , which may point out some exception to that case.